# Erro ao tentar inicializar o projeto Angular (To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false")

Tags: angular, angular-5, angular-cli

Peguei um projeto que estou estudando de um curso. Instalei as depedências do node com o comando `npm install` e deu tudo certo. 
Ao inicializar o webPack com o comando `ng serve` mostra essa erro:

> Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.1) is greater than your local
>   version (1.5.0). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

Alguém sabe o que fazer nesse caso ?

Comment: Mesma situação que está passando: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525746/global-angular-cli-version-greater-than-local-version

Comment: Me parece que o erro é causado pela instalação local e não global do angular-cli. O que a reposta recomenda fazer é instalar o angular-cli de forma global, `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest` execute esse comando em seu terminei e veja se o erro ainda continua.

Comment: Ainda assim não resolveu :(

Answer (score 0):

Tenho a mesma mensagem.

> Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.8) is greater than your local version (1.7.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

Isso não é uma mensagem de erro. Isso é um warning só avisando que você está com uma versão diferente do CLI no projeto e do instalado na sua maquina.

Você pode verificar isso no seu arquivo package.json. Você deve ter uma linha como essa abaixo só com a versão 1.5.0 como informado no seu warning.

```
"@angular/cli": "~1.7.3"
```

Você pode ocultar essa mensagem ou resolver.

Busque por atualizar projeto angular, esse [site](https://update.angular.io/) pode te auxiliar.

A Loiane postou sobre isso no [blog](https://loiane.com/2018/05/upgrading-to-angular-v6/) dela a pouco.

Espero que ajude.